# Multiple CFS files are generated in lucene 4.10.2

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying index around 612 record using lucene 4.10.2. It is creating lot of CFS files in index directory. Around 626 CFS file are created. It is taking more time to index. All CFS files are max 3kb.

ENV: java 8, window 7

```java
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(file);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_2, new ClassicAnalyzer());
if(bufferSizeMB != 0 && bufferSizeMB != -1){
    config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(bufferSizeMB);
}  else {
    config.setRAMBufferSizeMB(DEFAULT_RAM_BUFFER_SIZE_MB);
}      
config.setMaxBufferedDocs(1000);
config.setMaxBufferedDeleteTerms(1000);
config.setMergePolicy(new LogDocMergePolicy());
IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
iwriter.getConfig().setMaxBufferedDeleteTerms(1000);
iwriter.getConfig().setMaxBufferedDocs(1000);
iwriter.getConfig().setRAMBufferSizeMB(bufferSizeMB)
```

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Multiple-CFS-files-are-generated-in-lucene-4-10-2-td4176336.html

Comment: hey any updates on your question? did you find any solution or anything else that cleared your queries?

Answer (score 0):

From [change](http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/lucene/CHANGES.txt) document,

```
  LUCENE-4462: DocumentsWriter now flushes deletes, segment infos and builds
  CFS files if necessary during segment flush and not during publishing. The latter
  was a single threaded process while now all IO and CPU heavy computation is done
  concurrently in DocumentsWriterPerThread.
```

With the segmental flush, the merge is triggered according to your merge policy. Ideally after that if the indexing ends properly and the writer is closed, only one cfs file should remain.

Thats what I observed in my application.

**Update in response to the comment**

I recently migrated from 2.x to 4.10.2.

A quote from the indexwriter 4.10.2 [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#commit()).

```
Commits all pending changes (added & deleted documents, segment merges, added indexes, 
etc.) to the index, and syncs all referenced index files, such that a reader will see 
the changes and the index updates will survive an OS or machine crash or power loss. 
Note that this does not wait for any running background merges to finish. This may
be a costly operation, so you should test the cost in your application and do it only
when really necessary.
```

What you can do is instead use one indexwriter and add all your records using that without calling commit everytime. And finally when all the records are added just call `indexwriter.close()` which will take care of the merge and commit process.

Comment: Hi Sumeet, Thanks for you are response. We are migrating Lucene 2.4 to 4.10
When we run 612 records in 2.4 it took 10 mint and it created 10 CFS files in my local system.
Same 612 records in 4.10 it took 1hour and it created 626 CFS files created.  For both cases we are calling commit for each record.
My question is  for each commit in 2.4 it is updating the existing CFS file, in 4.10 it is creating new CFS. We are thinking because of this it is taking more time. How to avoid this.
In the above post you can find the link where screen shot is posted.